# playing and stopping using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, avplayer

I am trying to develop one radio app using AVPlayer which streams audio from a particular link. Done coding for that and there is no error but still its not playing the music.
Here is my **ViewController.m** which has a method called **playmusic**

```
-(void)playMusic{
NSString *radiourl = @"";
radiourl = @"somelink/listen.pls";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:radiourl];

masset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
mplayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:masset];
mplayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:mplayerItem];
mplayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

[mplayer play];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

}
```

and i have 1 more question that how am i supposed to stop the streaming because AVPlayer has only two methods **play** and **pause**.If i am using the pause method then it pauses the streaming and again if i play it plays from the same point where it has been paused last time. I want it to be live so i need something like stop. 
Please help as i am very new in this field.
Thank you.